# Mouse "scroll wheel" initially scrolls the wrong direction in MS Word in Draft mode over RDP

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, remote-desktop, mouse-wheel

I'm using MS Word a PC. I access the PC from a Mac using Remote Desktop. When I run MS Word while viewing a document in Draft mode on the PC and use the scroll wheel on the mouse attached to my Mac, Word initially scrolls the wrong direction and then starts scrolling the correct direction.

When MS Word on the PC is in Print Layout view, it doesn't have this problem. Edge on the PC doesn't have this problem. It always scrolls the correct direction. This is with an Apple Magic Mouse on the Mac. If I connect a Microsoft Comfort Mouse 4500 to my Mac, I don't see this behavior (it always scrolls the correct direction) even with MS Word in Draft mode.

How do I fix this so Word scrolls the correct direction from the start?

- MS Word on PC: Version 2008 (Build 13127.21348 Click-to-Run)
- PC: Dell OptiPlex 7040
- Windows: Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2 19044.3448
- Mac: Mac Pro (Late 2013)
- macOS: Monterey 12.6.8
- RDP client for macOS: Version 10.8.4 (2111)
- Mechanical scroll wheel mouse: Microsoft Comfort Mouse 4500
- Multi-touch Apple Magic Mouse: Model number: A1657